# Xcode Swift - Animating UIImageView Repetitively

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiimageview

just quick inquiry in regards to implementing an issue I'm having with animating a UIImageView. I successfully implemented animating an image to slide off screen; but i want it to reappear when it exists the view to simulate a side-scroller game animation.

Something like this:
[image]

I've tried implementing a completion handler but struggled understanding the logic of how to implement it, so I removed my attempts; so my code is left as follows:

```
let oldCenter = background.center
        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: oldCenter.x - 400, y: oldCenter.y)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.background.center = newCenter
        }) { (success: Bool) in
            print("Done moving image")
        }
```

An example or pointers on how to achieved my desired animation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let oldCenter = view.center
    let newCenter = CGPoint(x: oldCenter.x - 400, y: oldCenter.y)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: 
    [.curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {
      view.center = newCenter
    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat the animation,
 there is no need to implement the `completion`.
[animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622451-animatewithduration) has *`options`* parameter ([UIViewAnimationOptions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions?language=objc)), which is:

> A mask of options indicating how you want to perform the animations.
>   For a list of valid constants, see UIViewAnimationOptions.

One of the constants for the `UIViewAnimationOptions` is [*`repeat`*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622487-repeat):

> Repeat the animation indefinitely.

So, what you should do:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {
    self.background.center = newCenter
}, completion: nil)
```

Again, implementing `completion` is not required for repeating the animation, implementing it is up to your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try UIView UIView repeat option

```
    let oldCenter = background.center
    let newCenter = CGPoint(x: oldCenter.x - 400, y: oldCenter.y)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear, repeat], animations: {
        self.background.center = newCenter
    }) { (success: Bool) in
        print("Done moving image")
        if(success)
        {
          self.background.center = oldCenter
        }
    }
```